# How to compare all rows in a table and extract data using triggers

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one table stores the GPS data of various users and another table stores the idle time of the users based upon the GPS latitude and longitude values and timestamp difference.

Table T1 contents:

```
id  uid  latitude   longitude    received_time          imno
435 25  13.041868   80.198868   2014-08-07 15:53:00     352944054874253 
436 25  13.041862   80.198868   2014-08-07 15:54:00     352944054874253 
437 25  13.041869   80.198868   2014-08-07 15:55:00     352944054874253 
438 25  13.041887   80.198871   2014-08-07 15:55:38     352944054874253 
439 25  13.041887   80.198871   2014-08-07 15:55:42     352944054874253 
440 25  13.041887   80.198871   2014-08-07 15:55:47     352944054874253 
441 25  13.041887   80.198871   2014-08-07 15:55:52     352944054874253 
442 25  13.041887   80.198871   2014-08-07 15:56:00     352944054874253
```

I have to compare rows having the same latitude and longitude values.

If previous row's latitude and longitude is the same as the next row's latitude and longitude, then calculate timestamp difference until the next row's latitude and longitude values aren't equal.

For example, from ID 438 to 442 the latitude and longitude values are the same so I have to calculate:

```
timediff = 442 received - 438 received time (in minutes)
```

and store it in table T2 like:

```
id  uid     latitude     longitude      idle_time               imno
1    25      13.041887   80.198871    2014-08-07 00:01:38    352944054874253 

start_time                        end_time
2014-08-07 15:55:38         2014-08-07 15:56:00
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `id` is primary_key and auto increment column for both t1 and t2, I think this is what you need:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig1
AFTER INSERT ON t1
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF @latitude = NEW.latitude AND @longitude = NEW.longitude THEN
     SET @end_time = NEW.received_time;
     SET @iddle_time = TIMEDIFF(NEW.received_time, @start_time);
     UPDATE t2 SET iddle_time = @iddle_time, end_time = @end_time
               WHERE id = @last_id_t2;
  ELSE

     INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (NULL, NEW.uid, NEW.latitude, NEW.longitude, 
                            NULL, NEW.imno, NEW.received_time, NEW.received_time);       
     SET @last_id_t2 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
     SET @latitude = NEW.latitude; SET @longitude = NEW.longitude;
     SET @iddle_time = NULL;
     SET @start_time = NEW.received_time; SET @end_time = NEW.received_time;
  END IF;
END;
```

You can see the whole scheme here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a70ac/1

Answer (score 0):

I think a trigger based approach is not a good one and, depending on the requirements, could fail.

The first problem (this applies to any solution you implement) is that comparing floating point numbers with an equality operator is never recommended in any scientific computing application.  At the 1.0e-6 level, you are asking for about 0.1 m accuracy in GPS, which not possible for almost all consumer GPS devices.  The first thing you need to do is replace all the equality with something like *ABS(@latitude - new.latitude) > tol*, where *tol* is the tolerance that defines stationary.  One degree of longitude/latitude is roughly 60 nautical miles or 110 kilometers, so (if I did my math right) 1.0e-4 is about 10 meters.  Given the random variation in GPS positions, the tolerance value will result in some false positives and false negatives relative to being stationary.  Depending on the consequences of being wrong, you may want to bias your methodology one way or another.

Second, you will needlessly be pounding the idle table for no good reason.  Position reports are probably coming at a much faster rate than you will be consuming data from the idle table.  Depending on the number of GPS receivers and the update frequency, that could be a lot IOPS.

Third, can you assure that data will only come in with monotonically increasing timestamps?  If not, you may need some logic in your trigger handle that scenario.  Can data come in concurrently from the same user?  If yes, you may have to lock the idle table, which will kill performance.

With proper partitioning and indexing, I think your problem is better implemented as a view.